# How to check if a 2d array is in ascending order in c++?

Tags: c++, arrays, sorting

I can't get this function to return true, despite the fact that I've initialized the array in ascending order.

```
bool won(int gameBoard[][SIZE])
{
    for(int i=0;i<SIZE;i++)
    {
        for(int j=0;j<SIZE;j++)
        {
            if(gameBoard[i][j]>gameBoard[i][j+1]||gameBoard[i][j]>gameBoard[i+1][0])
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: `[j+1]` and `[i+1]` will be out of range when  `i` or `j` is at its maximum value.

Comment: how do I keep it in range?

Comment: @Jason Did your problem resolved?If yes,then you should accept an answer for future understanding of this question.

Answer (score 5):

You have two problem in your code.

**1. value of i and j becomes out of range at some stage.**

**2. condition to check if the array is in ascending order is wrong.**

Let's solve one by one

> 1. To keep the value of i,j inside the range change the for loop like this

### Before:

```
for(int i=0;i<SIZE;i++)
{
    for(int j=0;j<SIZE;j++)
    {
    }
}
```

### After:

```
for(int i=0;i<SIZE-1;i++)
{
    for(int j=0;j<SIZE-1;j++)
    {
    }
}
```

### Explanation:

What your program was facing wrong is when the value of `j` becomes `SIZE-1` you are checking if `gameBoard[i][j]>gameBoard[i][j+1]`.But `gameBoard[i][j+1]` will try to access `gameBoard[i][SIZE]` and you know that there is no value in that index because you saved value from 0 to SIZE-1.
Same problem happens with `i` when your program is checking the last row.

> 2. To fix the checking condition `if the array is in ascending order or not` change your condition like this:

### Before:

```
if(gameBoard[i][j]>gameBoard[i][j+1]||gameBoard[i][j]>gameBoard[i+1][0])
```

### After:

```
if((j!=SIZE-2 && gameBoard[i][j]>gameBoard[i][j+1])
||(j==SIZE-2 && ((gameBoard[i][j]>gameBoard[i][j+1])||(gameBoard[i][j+1]>gameBoard[i+1][0])))
```

### Explaination:

When the index of `j` is less than `SIZE-2` compare `gameBoard[i][j]` & `gameBoard[i][j+1]` and see if they breaks the condition or not.But when the index of `j` is equal to `SIZE-2`,we have to compare two things.One is compare `gameBoard[i][j]` with the next element `gameBoard[i][j+1]`,Another one is compare the next element of `j` with next rows first element `gameBoard[i+1][0]`.
N:B: Only that time you should check if `gameBoard[i][j]` is greater than `gameBoard[i+1][0]`,not everytime.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a much safer version that doesn't require to do any comparisons or check for indices wrapping around to the start of each row, all using the [std::is_sorted](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/is_sorted) algorithm function.

```
#include <algorithm>

// Assuming that the array is 10 x 10
#define SIZE 10 

bool won(int gameBoard[][SIZE])
{
    return std::is_sorted(&gameBoard[0][0], &gameBoard[SIZE-1][SIZE]);
}
```

Since a 2D array is contiguous, there is no need to write a loop, since the range starts from the address of the first item to the address one past the last item in the entire 2D array.

[Live Example](http://ideone.com/hVGwxd)

[Live Example showing that the test data is not sorted](http://ideone.com/QPuG6i)

Comment: You sure about the condition inside the for loop?
I think your program will output true for this type of input

/1 2 3 4/
/9 1 3 1/
..........
unsorted values...
Because you are just checking the first row and returning true.

Comment: @ash12 Isn't that what the OP wants, i.e. to determine if the array is in ascending order?

Comment: check my comment again..i've added a data.. in comment it's hard to add input

Comment: Then if the array is a true 2D array, then the answer is basically the same, since the data is contiguous.  Just that the range has to be expanded with no `for` loop being necessary.

Comment: Your second answer is more understandable and easier to implement. +1 from me. But please check out this https://paste.ubuntu.com/23930455/ and fix the first program,because it's not correct i think.

Comment: [This shows the unsorted data returns 0](http://ideone.com/jCL7tq).  Compare to [this example returning 1 for sorted data](http://ideone.com/HR6m4o).

Comment: The problem is in your first program. The second one is just fine.